# Collecting values from iterated intersections in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, intersection

I have a points feature class which I am intersecting with a number of polygon feature classes, one at a time (i.e. points AND polygons1, points AND polygons2, etc...).

Each time I do an intersection I note the number of points captured by the polygons layer I used. I have a modelbuilder model that goes through the first part of this process iteratively.

How can I collect the number of points intersected, relative to the polygon layer I used, as a list/table?

I'm trying to use the Collect Values tool to tabulate the number of points per intersection but I don't understand where the information is going. Should I be using a different tool?

I noticed that Get Count may be the tool I need to get the number of records geenrated after each intersection. However, I don't know how to output this information from successive iterations into different rows of a table.

[image]

Comment: I may have missed the point but I think the spatial join tool can do all this in one tool, no need to build a complex model as above. Have a look at that tool.

Comment: idk how that helps. what would i be joining since I want to tabulate the number of records from each intersection. At which point would you add the spatial join?

Comment: If you join points to polygons and make sure you have a one to many relation selected then you'll get a new dataset duplicating the polygons as many times as there are points intersecting. Then it is a simple summary stats tool by  polygon ID.

Comment: Thanks - i learnt smg new; your way is much easier and more powerful...i was working like a brute the other way!